# Right way of using Angular Factories and Services for this

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a sensible way of doing this.. kind of learning Angular as I go and I've got a bit confused..

I have a service

```
.service('Cameras', function(Camera){
    var _list = [];

  // public API
   this.list = _list;

  document.body.addEventListener("dbready", function(){
  loadCameras(function(result){
    for(var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
      _list.push(new Camera(result.rows.item(i).name, result.rows.item(i).ip, result.rows.item(i).id));
  });
  }, false);


 })
```

Which is attempting to use this factory

```
 .factory('Camera', function(name,ip,id) {

    this.name = name;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.videoFiles = [];
    this.photoFiles = [];
    this.battery = 0;
    this.space = 0;
})
```

To create the Camera objects.

I'm getting this error

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nameProvider <- name <- Camera <- Cameras

Which I assume is because I;m not injecting the Camera factory into the Camera services properly - and I'm probably going about this the wrong way - but can anyone let me know the right way!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You declared Camera as an Angular service.

The Camera service needs to be injected with the service 'name', the service 'ip' and the service 'id'. These services don't exist.

Remember that a service is **a singleton**. Their factory can take other services as arguments, but not data like a name, an ip or an id: where would Angular get these data when creating the unique Camera instance?

If you need such parameters to build a camera, then it shouldn't be a service at all. Just a regular JavaScript constructor function. And it should thus not be injected into the `Cameras` service.

Also note that the Camera doesn't do anything with the id passed as argument.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. The real issue is that I want to use angular services such as $http from the regular Javascript contructor. Is this possible if it's just a JS function?

Comment: I wouldn't make $http calls from a constructor, but you can inject $http into Cameras(), and pass it to the Camera constructor, along with name, ip, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a service in another service requires you injecting the service into it

Try injecting the `Camera` factory directly into the service

```
.service('Cameras',['Camera', function(Camera){
    var _list = [];

  // public API
   this.list = _list;

  document.body.addEventListener("dbready", function(){
  loadCameras(function(result){
    for(var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
      _list.push(new Camera(result.rows.item(i).name, result.rows.item(i).ip, result.rows.item(i).id));
  });
  }, false);


 }])
```

Comment: The OP is already injecting Camera into Cameras. You're just using another, more complex syntax to do it. And, BTW, what is injected is a service, not a factory. The factory is the function used to create the service.